# La metà più uno

Tags: adverbs, grammatical-number

"La metà più uno" is singular or plural? Which option do you think is better?

«Sia presente la metà più uno» (singular), or «Siano presenti la metà più uno» (plural)?

Thank for your suggestions,
Andy

Gentili amici,

l'espressione "la metà più uno" è singolare o plurale? Secondo voi è meglio scrivere «sia presente la metà più uno» al singolare, oppure «siano presenti la metà più uno» al plurale?

Grazie per l'aiuto,
Andy

Comment: Definitely singular, although I'd personally write *Sia presente la maggioranza*. Could you give some context?

Comment: It's frequently used in a legal context. It means the majority, but I've found both these examples being used. For instance:«L'assemblea è valida qualora sia presente la metà più uno dei consiglieri», or «L'assemblea è valida qualora siano presenti la metà più uno dei consiglieri». I was thinking that "più" works like an "e", so it should be plural, although maybe the singular is more frequent. And, in any case, "la metà più uno" means at least two (people).

Comment: I'm really terrible on "legalese", so I'm not going to write down an answer but I am still convinced that it should be singular (to me it sounds as a collective noun, like *sciame*, *gregge*, *folla*; those are singular even if they denote a plurality).

Comment: Ricordo bene quando un collega, in vena di cavilli, sosteneva che, in caso di numero dispari di presenti, diciamo 15, una delibera richiedesse 9 voti favorevoli, perché “la metà più uno fa 8.5”. Trovo che “la metà più uno” o, peggio, “il 50% più uno” sia una locuzione da evitare con cura. In italiano si dice “la maggioranza”, come ricorda @DenisNardin.

Comment: Tutto giusto su “la metà più uno” (e tecnicamente è inconfutabile il ragionamento dei 9 voti favorevoli), ma uno statuto o simili deve anche prevedere esplicitamente di quale maggioranza (assoluta, relativa, qualificata e in che misura) si stia parlando. In realtà nel nostro caso la formula più semplice sarebbe “più della metà”.

Comment: I like the fact that we are "gentili amici" in the Italian version but not in English. :)

Comment: On stackexchange, the opening 'dear friends' is cut off automatically. I'm so sorry!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, Siccome SE e' strettamente domanda e risposta tutte le cortesie, humor, ecc vengono tagliati, pensa che in altre sezioni di SE c'e' chi si prende la briga di scorrere le varie domande e fare pulizia correggendole... (da matti)... e pure questo mio commento e' contro le regole in teoria...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direi – ma apprezzerei una conferma – che sia preferibile usare il singolare perché, nonostante l'apparenza, “più” non è una congiunzione e quindi non si comporta necessariamente come “e”.
“Più” è qui un avverbio, e quindi proviamo a pensare ad altre frasi in cui “la metà” venga modificato usando avverbi: “Sia presente la metà compiutamente” o, più vicino come significato, “Sia presente la metà insieme a chi la sostiene”.

Comment: Grazie, DaG. Ciò che mi convince nella tua argomentazione è il fatto che, essendo avverbio, più non si comporta come una congiunzione. L'ultimo esempio che hai dato è molto calzante. Grazie.